# Как проверить совпадают ли элементы у массивов и изъять те которые не совпадают JavaScript

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Здравствуйте, друзья,
У меня есть функция которая проверяет элементы в массиве и возвращает те, которые прошли проверку.
Как изменить условия чтобы она возвращала те элементы, которые проверку не прошли?
Простая смена `==` на `!=` не работает

```
function areIn(oldAra) {
    return function(elem) {
        var returnArr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < oldAra.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < elem.length; j++) {
                if(elem[j] == oldAra[i]) {
                    returnArr.push(elem[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return returnArr;
    };
}
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var check = areIn(arr);
console.log(check([2, 3, 4, 10])); //[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function areIn(oldAra) {
    return function(elem) {
        var returnArr = [], tmp = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < oldAra.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < elem.length; j++) {
                if(elem[j] == oldAra[i]) {
                    tmp[elem[j]] = true;
                } else {
                    if (!tmp[elem[j]]) {
                      tmp[elem[j]] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
                    
        for (var key in tmp) {
            if (!tmp[key]) {
                returnArr.push(key);
            }
        }
        
        return returnArr;
    };
}
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var check = areIn(arr);
console.log(check([2, 3, 4, 10])); //[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function areIn(oldAra) {
  return function(elem) {
    return elem.filter(item => oldAra.indexOf(item) < 0);
  };
}
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var check = areIn(arr);
console.log(check([2, 3, 4, 10])); //[10]
```